# Is there a way to retrieve data from a remote MyPHP database to a Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, phpmyadmin

I've been working on a WP7 application that locates the nearest 'alternative' sports centre based on your GPS location using a database of alternative sports locations (The idea being to promote less popular sports amongst university students).

However, the app has to connect to a MyPHP database hosted on a wordpress website. I have the details required to access it but there isn't much literature on the web about using a WCF service to connect to a remote database. I was wondering if there was a (preferebly) easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is simply a frontend for a database. It is generally MySQL. So the question then becomes "How can I access data in MySQL from Windows Phone".

Create a WCF service that uses Linq to access the Data in MySQL. Then access this WCF service from windows phone.

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou. I'm very new to databases so appreciate the help. If anyone is wondering how to do this, I found this guide: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/urmimalapal/creating-a-windows-phone-7-application-consuming-data-using-a-wcf-service/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pay for a .NET server / hosting - you can use .php files to return the data in JSON format directly from your MySQL database. For a list of users you can do something like this:

```
<?php

  /* connect to the db */
  include '../conn.php';

  /* grab the users from the db */
  $query = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Users";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

  /* create one master array of the records */
  $users = array();
  if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      array_push($users, $user);
    }
  }

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array('users'=>$users));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has begun to construct a Windows phone 8 application to interface with some phpmyadmin instances. The work is in progress. he might get some help from the community because the project has a great number of potential subscribers ! check out XYD on Windows Store : [http://goo.gl/PJiYsU](http://goo.gl/PJiYsU%20!) !